# Change structure of an array according to number of related elements - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that i trying to export to excel with `SheetJs` and I've a problem to convert my data structure the needed data structure.
here are the all the details:

**SheetJs wanted header**

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6']
```

**My array:(with the wanted position inside the new array)**

```
[
    1 {key1: 'text1'},
    1 {key2: 'text2'},
    2 {key2: 'text6'},
    1 {key3: 'text3'},
    1 {key4: 'text4'},
    2 {key4: 'text5'},
    3 {key4: 'text5'},
    1 {key5: 'text6'},
    1 {key6: 'text7'}
]
```

**Wanted result:**

```
[
    {'key1': 'text1', 'key2': 'text2', 'key3': 'text3', 'key4': 'text4', 'key5': 'text6', 'key6': 'text7' },
    {'key2', 'text1', 'key2': 'text2', 'key4': 'text5'},
    {'key4': 'text5'},
]
```

As you can see I want to restructure the elements according the the number of the appearance of the elements.

I can't even describe what I've tried In the last few hours, stuff like converting the results to an array and hashmap and so, but I just can't get the wanted results.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any additional information aside from the original array to indicate which result object a given key/value should be part of? Is it just the order they are encountered (i.e. the first key1/2/3... go to the first result, the next time one is encountered it goes to the subsequent result)?

Comment: @smashed-potatoes Thank you for youre help. I just need to keep the key value as they and only to create the object as I described to order don't matter . Here is an example from the sheetJs documentation: `var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([
  { S:1, h:2, e:3, e_1:4, t:5, J:6, S_1:7 },
  { S:2, h:3, e:4, e_1:5, t:6, J:7, S_1:8 }
], {header:["S","h","e","e_1","t","J","S_1"]});`

Comment: If order doesn't matter, how do you know which output row a given key/value input is part of? Also, In your wanted result you have `'key2': 'text2'` for both the first and second result - should the second actually be `'text6'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the desired result correctly:

- You would like to create an array of result objects based an array of input objects
- The input objects have 1 or more key/value pairs
- The result objects are the merged result of the input objects, putting recurring keys to their own object

To achieve this, you can break down the logic as:

1. Iterate over the input array objects and their key/value pairs
2. Append values to the first result object without the given key
3. If there is no result object without a given key, add a new result object with the key/value

What this looks like:

```js
const inputArray = [
  {key1: 'text1'},
  {key2: 'text2'},
  {key2: 'text6'},
  {key3: 'text3'},
  {key4: 'text4'},
  {key4: 'text5'},
  {key4: 'text5'},
  {key5: 'text6'},
  {key6: 'text7'}
]

const resultArray = [];

// Loop over the input key/value objects
inputArray.forEach((inputItem) => {

  // Loop over each key/value pair of the input objects (appears to usually be one)
  Object.entries(inputItem).forEach(([key, value]) => {

    // Search the result array for an existing object without the given key
    let outputIndex = -1;
    for (let i=0; i<resultArray.length; i++) {
      if (!(key in resultArray[i])) {
        outputIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    };

    // If there is a target output object, set the value for the key
    if (outputIndex !== -1) {
      resultArray[outputIndex][key] = value;
    } else {
      // No target result object, create a new one with the key/value
      resultArray.push({ [key]: value });
    }
  });
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Breliant!! Thank you very much.